# WooCommerce Recover Cart from Session Data

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working for a tiny Abandon Cart Recovery Plugin and I need to recover the cart from `woocommerce_sessions` table.

Here is the unserialiezed cart data for 1 variable product in cart.

```
array (size=1)
  'cart' => 
    array (size=9)
      'product_id' => int 22
      'variation_id' => int 24
      'variation' => 
        array (size=1)
          'attribute_pa_color' => string 'green' (length=5)
      'quantity' => int 1
      'line_total' => float 20
      'line_tax' => int 0
      'line_subtotal' => int 20
      'line_subtotal_tax' => int 0
      'line_tax_data' => 
        array (size=2)
          'total' => 
            array (size=0)
              empty
          'subtotal' => 
            array (size=0)
              empty
```

I'm trying to recover the whole cart with this data. I know it's possible to to loop through this array and add items to cart via

```
WC_Cart::add_to_cart( $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variation );
```

But is there any more elegant way to do it as the data is stored in `woocommerce_sessions` table and totally WooCommerce compatible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't find any other solution regarding this, so just cleared the cart first and then gone through a loop with the cart data and added the items to cart programmatically. Here is the code looks like.

```
if ( $cart_data ) {
    WC()->cart->empty_cart();

    foreach ( $cart_data as $product ) {

        // Validate Product data
        $product_id   = isset( $product['product_id'] )    ? (int) $product['product_id']   : 0;
        $quantity     = isset( $product['quantity'] )      ? (int) $product['quantity']     : 1;
        $variation_id = isset( $product['variation_id'] )  ? (int) $product['variation_id'] : 0;
        $variation    = isset( $product['variation'] )     ? $product['variation']          : array();

        WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variation );
    }
    WC()->cart->calculate_totals();
}
```